# Android Studio 0.2.8 TODO colors have changed

Tags: android, user-interface, intellij-idea, android-studio

Just updated to Android Studio 0.2.8 and suddenly my `TODO` items are colored blue, which makes them completely unreadable using the Dracula scheme.

The color setting in `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` -> `General` -> `TODO defaults` is unchanged from before the update, but it is not being used.

The pattern in `TODO` is also set to `Use color scheme TODO default colors`.

Is there anywhere else that specifies the color of the `TODO` items?

**EDIT**
This seems to happen in IntelliJ IDEA as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've figured it out but I will post this anyway, in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

The solution was to go to `Settings` -> `TODO` and toggle the `Use color scheme TODO default colors` setting off and back on for the `\btodo\b.*` pattern. It then reverted to using the color I set in the `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts` section.

**Edit:**
Just to be clear, after toggling the setting off, I first accepted the change by closing settings, then I went back into settings, and toggled it back on again.

Comment: you can count Ubuntu in, too :). 

@free3dom: Have you filed a bug on this?

Comment: @chester1000 ..I had thought about filing a bug, but forget all about it. [Just did it now](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60141) ...thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Turns out it is a bug in the IntelliJ codebase. They are aware of it :)